# Using Process.GetProcesses()then MainWindowTitle to filter GUI Applications

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I’m trying to build the “Applications” section of Task Manger using GetProcesses and then MainWindowTitle to filter GUI Applications. This worked well for me to begin with but I’ve now noticed that using “MainWindowTitle” does not always work because if an application has been inactive (This inactive time randomly changes but happens especially with “Outlook”), the “MainWindowTitle” disappears and becomes empty so it does not show on my Application list. I would then need to click on the “missing” application for it to be shown again. I was wondering if this sounds normal that the “MainWindowTitle” property field would become empty if inactive and then reappear again?

I was under the assumption from searching around the internet that this property is the best way to filter GUI applications (Another method would be to use EnumDesktopWindows) unless anyone else has come across something else I could use?

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EnumDesktopWindows` with `GetWindowThreadProcessId` so that you can tie them both together.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I’ll give this a go while I wait to see if anyone else has any suggestions.